# Columns in long table repositioned on next page

Tags: tables, tabularx, ltablex

I've created two long tables with two columns which stretch over several pages. I would like the columns of both tables to be aligned in a vertical line. However, whenever one of the two columns continues on the next page, the column position shifts on every new page (see example below). It looks like it repositions them depending on the width of the values within the cells. How can I keep the columns in a vertical line? Thanks!

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\section*{Abbreviations}%
    \vskip -2em
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
      Aβ & Amyloid beta \\
      AD & Alzheimer's disease \\
      ALS & Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis \\
      etc.
      UTR & Untranslated region \\
      vCJD & Variant CJD \\
      WT & Wild-type \\
    \end{tabularx}

\section*{Gene names}
    \vskip -2em
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\itshape}lX}
        ACTB & Actin Beta \\
        APP & Amyloid Precursor Protein \\
        AQP4 & Aquaporin 4 \\
        etc.
        TMEM119 & Transmembrane Protein 119 \\
    \end{tabularx}
```

Here's a screenshot of what the table currently looks like when continuing on the next page:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be due to the fact that inner margin is not equal to outer margin. You can check this loading `geometry`  with the same value for the left and right margins

Comment: longtable columns are the same width for the whole table, but the margins depend on the document class and other code that you have not shown. the margins are unrelated to longtable, presumably if you had plain text the margins also change on odd and even pages

Comment: also the image shown is not generated by the code shown which makes it very hard to answer. please edit so the example is a complete small document that shows the issue.